.ASPXAUTH cookie not being read by sub application
I have an asp.net v4.7.2 web app setup at, my.example.com in IIS. It uses asp.net Forms Authentication. It's Web.Config:
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" defaultUrl="~/User/Default.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="30" requireSSL="true" />
</authentication>

<roleManager defaultProvider="SqlProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" applicationName="MyApp" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="30">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" applicationName="MyApp" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="25" />
  </providers>
</membership>

I have another asp.net v4.7.2 web app via IIS > Add Application as my.example.com/test. It gets Forms Authentication inherited from the parent site's web.config and I am able to confirm this by getting the list of Roles and Users programmatically. BUT when I check for authentication using User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, it is always false. It's Web.config:
<authentication>
    <forms loginUrl="~/../Default.aspx">
    </forms>
</authentication>

The sub-site sees only the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie, with the same value as the parent, but not the .ASPXAUTH cookie (checked by logging the cookies). I think, if it can see the Auth cookie, it should be able to validate and IsAuthenticated should become true.
How do I read authentiation from the parent site https://my.example.com in the sub-application https://my.example.com/test

Figured it out.
I thought there was a root level machine key but IIS has a per site setting of auto generating the machine key for each individual application. As soon as clicked Generate Keys in IIS for the parent site, it added a machine key to the web.config and that was inherited by the sub app too:

 <system.web>
   <machineKey decryptionKey="A9...." validationKey="85...." />
 </system.web>

